# Создание каталога

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Очень давно маюсь с созданием каталога на сайте.

Хотел бы узнать как всё же создать каталог и по возможности подкаталог.

Пример: site.ru/каталог или с подкаталогом site.ru/каталог/подкаталог/

Сайт обычный с pma(phpmyadmin)

Comment: А при чем тут вообще phpmyadmin и mysql?

Comment: Я написал для информации.. мало ли будут вопросы: сайт на php или простые страницы html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ссылки вида *http://site.ru/questions/something_else/* называются [ЧПУ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3_%28%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%29).
На самом деле никаких папок *questions* и *something_else* может не существовать. В этом случае, вам надо почитать про [mod_rewrite и htaccess](http://www.seoblog.com.ua/2008/11/04/kratkoe-rukovodstvo-po-htaccess-and-mod_rewrite/)

P.S. Могу рассказать о том способе, который использую лично.
В .htaccess прописываю:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

В самом верху документа index.php подключаю файл-обработчик
в котором с помощью *$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']* получаю строку примерно такого вида:  /questions/something_else/, которую разделяю на составляющие:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = explode("/", $url);
```

"Убьём" в получившемся массиве пустые элементы и получим отдельные значения, использование которых - дело техники.

Comment: Вот спасибо большое.. :)
Примерно такое находил но было мало информации, а тут полностью :)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос неясен.

Если нужна просто папка на сервере, то она создается средствами ОС:

```
mkdir -p path
```

Если нужно папку создавать во время работы сайта, то дело сводится к выполнению той же команды ОС из php (при условии наличии необходимых прав на выполнение)

```
exec('mkdir -p path');
```

Если нужно манипулировать с доступом к папкам, это делается выставлением прав или директивами Апача (или другого веб-сервера)

```
<Directory path>
   ...
</Directory>
```

Comment: Я вот имел ввиду каталог...
Вот допустим http://hashcode.ru/ и мне нужно сделать http://hashcode.ru/questions так, и чтобы выводилась нужная информация на этой странице.
Допустим это будут статьи, нажал, появились статьи или же галерея.